# Is it possible to covert live stream of flv into 3gp format in java

Tags: java, flash

I am getting live streaming from `FMS` server in flv format. My java application is receiving `FLV` stream which is to be converted into different format such as **3gp**. Since it is a live stream therefore it is recommended to preserve the content of stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some applications (Aimersoft).It can capture live stream and it has got built in converter whic can convert to any format after capturing video.But u need url of video to be recorded. 
http://www.aimersoft.com/

Or You can have look on it xuggler

http://www.xuggle.com/

It has libraries to manage Video codecs.

Comment: I want to make my own converter which will convert live stream coming from 'FMS' to multiple formats.Do you have any idea of its possibility on basis of figures and facts

Comment: Yes i am looking 4 that and even got a sample code to do this

Comment: I have got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.Util.report(Ljava/lang/String);V  while executing xuggler program